# How do I refresh a ListItem or reload it from an URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

**Problem:** In the `foreach` below, I have 2 parts.

Part 1 opens an excel File and modifies it
Part 2 updates 3 of the `ListItem` fields

Both parts work individually but with them both enabled, Part 2 fails do to `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'Version conflict.'` understandably

**Question:** How can I refresh/reload my ListItem?

I tried `ListItem.RefreshLoad();`
And I looked all over for something along the lines of `ListItem.GetFromURL();` but can't seem to find what I'm looking for

```
            ClientContext cc = new ClientContext(site)
            SecureString pass = new SecureString();
            Web web = cc.Web;

            foreach (char c in "password".ToCharArray())
            {
                pass.AppendChar(c);
            }

            cc.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("User@Domain.com", pass);

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyLibrary");

            CamlQuery qry = new CamlQuery
            {
                ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Active'/><Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>"
            };
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(qry);

            cc.Load(listItems);
            cc.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem listItem in listItems)
            {

                //PART 1
                //Open the file
                //Modify the File
                //Save the file

                //PART 2
                listItem["Updated"] = DateTime.Now;
                listItem["Update_x0020_Duration"] = totalTime;
                listItem["System_x0020_Comment"] = "TestComment";
                listItem.Update();
                cc.ExecuteQuery();
            }
```

Comment: Is your spreadsheet synced to the list you are updating?

Comment: Synced to what? Part 1 is all being done in C# also. It was just a lot of bloat code so I didn't put it here. This is running in an SSIS package

Comment: Have you tried placing the `cc.ExecuteQuery();` outside `foreach` loop ?